# What means PREFIX=${1:-daily} in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

What means these declarations in bash script:

```
PREFIX=${1:-daily}

PROFILE=${2:-backup}
```

Comment: Did you try running them and understand it yourself?

Comment: Is all inside `man bash` - once open just type `/\:-`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means, assign `the first argument` (if present), else `daily` to variable `PREFIX` and assign `the second argument` (if present), else `backup` to variable `PROFILE`

eg:

```
$ cat file.sh
#!/bin/bash

PREFIX=${1:-daily}
PROFILE=${2:-backup}

echo $PREFIX
echo $PROFILE
```

For the following command line args given, output would be like:

```
$ ./file.sh
daily
backup

$ ./file.sh abc
abc
backup

$ ./file.sh abc xyz
abc
xyz
```

Answer (score 4):

The key here is to understand what Parameter-Expansion `${PARAMETER:-WORD}` syntax means here,

```
${PARAMETER:-WORD}

If the parameter PARAMETER is unset (never was defined) or null (empty), this one
expands to WORD, otherwise it expands to the value of PARAMETER, as if it
just was ${PARAMETER}
```

In your case the `${PARAMETER}` being the positional arguments passed to a function or script,

Use the below script for a better understanding,

```
myTestFunction() {
    PREFIX=${1:-daily}
    PROFILE=${2:-backup}

    printf "PREFIX value %s PROFILE value %s\n" "$PREFIX" "$PROFILE"
}

myTestFunction "some" "junk"
myTestFunction
```

which produces a result as

```
$ bash script.sh
PREFIX value some PROFILE value junk
PREFIX value daily PROFILE value backup
```

Also see the expanded debugger version of the script as

```
$ bash -x script.sh
+ myTestFunction some junk
+ PREFIX=some
+ PROFILE=junk
+ printf 'PREFIX value %s PROFILE value %s\n' some junk
PREFIX value some PROFILE value junk
+ myTestFunction
+ PREFIX=daily
+ PROFILE=backup
+ printf 'PREFIX value %s PROFILE value %s\n' daily backup
PREFIX value daily PROFILE value backup
```

how shell substitutes the values to the variables when `$1` or `$2` is not passed.

The syntax is *generally* used when by default you want to configure a variable with a certain value *at the same time* make it dynamically configurable also.

Answer (score 2):

Assigns value of first argument to PREFIX variable if this first argument exist, "daily" if it does not.